# Rails cache records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Is it a good idea to cache records with `Rails.cache`?

I want to cache last 15 records and show them.

For example 
in model

```
    def last_fifteens
     last(15).map(&:title)
    end

   def cached
     Rails.cache.write('last_fifteens',last_fifteens,expires_in: 1.hour)
   end

   def self.fetch_last_fifteens
     Rails.fetch('last_fifteens')
   end
```

and than on view

```
Product.fetch_last_fifteens
```

or it's a bad approach?

Answer (score 0):

Caching queries as simple as the one mentioned above will not have any significant impact(other than making your codebase more complicated) on your application in most cases(unless your app gets traffic comparable to Twitter or Facebook, which is highly unlikely :)). Such low level optimisations should only be performed once application performance is being monitored and benchmarked.

However looking at the sample code above, the code could be perhaps improved. There are two possible conditions

**A default scope does not exist for the model**

You have nothing to worry about.

**The model has a default scope**

Its always a good practice to look at the query being formed. In most scenarios, the solution wouldn't be optimal. E.g.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { order("locations.name ASC") }
end
```

Over here when I invoke Location.last(15), the following database query will be performed:

```
SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` ORDER BY locations.name asc
```

In other words, we're fetching all the locations from the database, then in Ruby,  the result set is being filtered to the last 15 array elements only. If the locations table has a really large amount of entries, we're essentially fetching all of them and just slicing our data set to the last 15 entries.

In this case it makes more sense to write our own method which is the inverse of the default_scope.

Also it makes sense to make sure that the aprropriate indexes exist